# How do I open a .txt file and create XML tags in Python?

Tags: python, xml, tags

I'm a noob programmer and am trying to open a bunch of .txt files containing data on each row so I can create XML tags for each row. For example, if the .txt file to open and tag looked like this:

```
John Smith
Harvard
4.00
1600
```

I need to use XML tags in Python to have it look like this:

```
<name> John Smith </name>
<university> Harvard </university>
<gpa> 4.00 </gpa>
<sat> 1600 </sat>
```

This seems like a fairly simple thing to do, though for some reason I can't locate a source on how to do so. I'm using Python 3.3, can someone help?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229/xml-writing-tools-for-python will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for your example:

```
tags = ['name', 'university', 'gpa', 'sat']
xml = ''

with open('data.txt') as data:
    # Reading data and filtering out the whitespace
    lines = [line.strip() for line in data.readlines()]

    # Generating xml
    xml = '\n'.join(['<{0:s}> {1:s} </{0:s}>'.format(tag, value)
                 for tag, value in zip(tags, lines)])
```